# Using AND & OR operator together in re.search in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there a way to use AND & OR operator together in re.search in python?

```
if re.search(r'xyz|abc', line) != None:
```

Here I have used OR operator, But my requirement is to get line containing (`'xyz'` or `'abc'`) and `'pqr'`. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore the order of the strings you can use

```
if re.search(r'(?=.*[pqr])(?=.*[xyz|abc])', line):
    print('match')

line = 'xyzpqr' # match
line = 'pqrxyz' # match
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search( r'(xyz|abc)pqr', 'abcpqr' )
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fa3055bdeb0>
>>> re.search( r'(xyz|abc)pqr', 'abcpq' )
>>>
```

Comment: @Guy would not work with `hello world` either, so what?

Comment: The requirement is *containing ('xyz' or 'abc') and 'pqr'*. `'pqrabc'` should pass.

Comment: @Guy yep, in that particular order. whatever you're proposing is out of order

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
re.search(r'((xyz|abc).*pqr)|(pqr.*(xyz|abc))', line)
```